# css multiple backgrounds positioning

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a background in place on my wordpress theme,

I have another image which I would like to position it in the center of the page and horizontally repeat it from left to right.

very similar to this website http://www.tcs.com/homepage/Pages/default.aspx

any tips or instructions is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would use a wrapper to accomplish this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(image1.jpg);
}
#wrapper {
background-position: center middle;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(image2.jpg);
background-repeat: x-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [multiple background images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) with CSS3 like this:

```
body {
  background: url(first_image.png) top left no-repeat,
              url(second_image.png) center center repeat-x;
}
```

You just have to separate the rules with a comma.  It's [pretty widely supported](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds).

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/4S5HR/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you have your original background image. If it was attached to the html like this

```
html {
    background: url(original-background.png) top left repeat-x;
    }
```

You could attach the repeating horizontal image to the body like this

```
body {
    background: url(repeating-background.png) top center repeat-x;
    }
```

Could you provide some more details as to how your css is and I can give you a more detailed answer but this should work for what you require.